# How to know which file to edit on wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I have a wordpress theme of 'Couponis' and I want to edit some code inside a popup window of the coupon when pressing on 'Get Code' but I do not know which file to edit.

here is example of the theme:
http://demo.spoonthemes.net/themes/couponis/home-2/

So how to know which file I should go to

Comment: Use a code editor (eg. Visual Studio Code) and try to find the piece of code you want to edit (you may need to download the website to your computer first if you haven't done so already though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know which file to edit, simply install the [Show Current Template](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/) plugin.

Having said that, the best practice to add custom code into a WordPress theme is by creating a child-theme.  This method allows your custom code to remain intact when the parent theme is updated. You can find more about [child themes here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

I hope you find this useful.

Cheers

Comment: I used the plugin and it worked thanks a lot for your help. but I have little problem which is i deal with a little popup screen for a coupon that pops up above the original screen and the plugin can see only the original screen, not the popup one

Comment: Alex,  I am happy to hear you like the Show Current Template plugin.  After looking at your site, I see you are using a premium theme by spoonthemes.net and assume you are using a page builder to assemble your pages. I suggest you reach out to the theme's author for further assistance on customizing the code that creates the popups.   

Good luck.